# Is it possible to read response headers server side?

Tags: php, http, laravel-5

Hey if you have to Laravel 5 apps, A & B

I want to set header paramaters on A and redirect to B and read those headers in app B.

```
redirect()->to($url)->headers('Key', $key);
```

this sends the headers in the response and thats fine but how do I read them server side?

Thanks

Comment: You don't read them. You already know them server-side as you're the one sending them. How do you read contents of the letter you write? Now comes the part where you're more confused than ever and we ask you "what is it that you're trying to accomplish?" It's a common thing known as [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: I am posting login data to an external app and then trying to receive headers on the redirect back to my app, because having an authentication key in the url is considered back practice right?

Comment: Great, that completely changes what you're after then! You want to post data to another server and read the response. What you're doing is sending response to a browser. What you really want to be asking is "How do I make a POST to another website and read the output". I suggest editing the title and the question to reflect that. After you read the response, you want to issue a response back to the client's browser. You do  this by `curl`- ing the external app, or using a library such as [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

Comment: The redirect is handled by the client. A redirect from server A to server B is basically an instruction to the client from server A that says "I got your request, now go to this URL at server B". Server A will never see a request from that client again, unless they go back to server A. So unless server A and server B have some other way of communicating, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem possible as the flow is:

```
1) browser -[request]-> A
2) browser <-[redirect]- A
3) browser -[request]-> B
4) browser <-[content]- B
```

Your response headers on step 2 are not automatically sent to server B in the next request (that is automatically executed by the browser due to the redirect).

A workaround that comes to my mind is to add they key to the $url as a get parameter like this:

```
$url = $url.'?Key='.urlencode($key);
```

On application B you can do a redirect to remove the 'Key' parameter from the address bar, when it is set.